# How do i assign a template on PageLayoutView Preview in TYPO3 10?

Tags: templates, typo3, preview, typo3-10.x

I would like to assign a template on my PageLayoutView preview in order to avoid writing HTML on my PHP files and better maintain it. How can i achieve that using TYPO3 10?

I would like to use it for example on the `textmedia` content element and add the subheader in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you will have to use the Standalone view. I would write a function which i can call it whenever i want to use it. Normally i would include the function on a Helper Class but for the sake of this answer i will put it on the same class. So lets say we have the `textmedia` content element and we want to add fields on the backend Preview.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView;

/**
 * Contains a preview rendering for the page module of CType="textmedia"
 */
class TextMediaPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{
    /**
     * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element of type "textmedia"
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
     * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionality
     * @param string $headerContent Header content
     * @param string $subheaderContent Subheader content
     * @param string $itemContent Item content
     * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
     */
    public function preProcess(
        PageLayoutView &$parentObject,
        &$drawItem,
        &$headerContent,
        &$subheaderContent,
        &$itemContent,
        array &$row
    ) {

         if ($row['CType'] === 'textmedia') {

             $standaloneView = $this->getStandAloneConfig();

             /*Disable TYPO3's default backend view configuration */
             $drawItem = false;

               
             /*Assign all the results to the backend */
             $standaloneView->assignMultiple([
                'title'             => $parentObject->CType_labels[$row['CType']],
                'type'              => $row['CType'],
                'content'           => $row,
               
             ]);

             $itemContent .= $standaloneView->render();
         }
     }

     public function getStandAloneConfig()
     {
        $standaloneView = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
        $standaloneView->setLayoutRootPaths([10,'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/']);
        $standaloneView->setTemplateRootPaths([10,'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/']);
        $standaloneView->setPartialRootPaths([10,'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/']);
        $standaloneView->setFormat('html');
        $standaloneView->setTemplate('PageLayoutView.html');

        return $standaloneView;
    }
```

**What is happening is the following**

First, we get the StandAlone configuration. In this configuration (`getStandAloneConfig()`) we set the path to where our templates, partials and layouts are. Then we assign the type (`html`) and then the name of the template where our preview is going to be built on (`PageLayoutView.html`).

After that we reset everything that TYPO3 writes on the Preview (`$drawItem = false;`) so we can write our own.

Last and not least we assign the variables which we are going to use on the HTML file.

Under **your_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/PageLayoutView.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <f:switch expression="{type}">
        <f:case value="textmedia">
            <f:render partial="Textmedia" arguments="{_all}"/>
        </f:case>
        <f:case value="text">
            <f:render partial="Text" arguments="{_all}"/>
        </f:case>
       <f:defaultCase>
            <f:render partial="Header" arguments="{_all}"/>
        </f:defaultCase>
    </f:switch>
</html>
```

I personally use the `PageLayoutView.html` as a controller which decides, which partial should be rendered. So i assign the variable `{type}` and i render the partial based on its value.

Under **your_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/Textmedia.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

   <p><strong class="element_title">{title}</strong></p>
   <table class="element_table">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th>Subheader</th>
             <td>{content.subheader}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</html>
```

Now you can look what is inside the `{content}` variable and render it on your HTML.

If you want to style your Preview you can do the following: Under your **ext_tables.php** add the following line:

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['stylesheet'] = 'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Css/Backend/page-layout-view.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty easy way. Just set an alternative path for the preview templates.

\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView::tt_content_drawItem():

```
// If the previous hook did not render something,
// then check if a Fluid-based preview template was defined for this CType
// and render it via Fluid. Possible option:
// mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview.media = EXT:site_mysite/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/Media.html
if ($drawItem) {
    $fluidPreview = $this->renderContentElementPreviewFromFluidTemplate($row);
    if ($fluidPreview !== null) {
        $out .= $fluidPreview;
        $drawItem = false;
    }
}
```